Netplan 'ignore-carrier' option doesn't work on 22.04 Ubuntu
So I have a machine running 22.04 ubuntu with a RJ45 ethernet card with two ports. One port has a cable plugged in, the other doesn't. The ideal situation is that I can configure both ports with an IP addr, static or assigned, carrier or no carrier. I've successfully produced this behavior on 20.04 ubuntu using the ignore-carrier option in my netplan yaml. However, this doesn't seem to translate to 22.04 for some reason. I can set a static IP or have dhcp assign an IP to the port that has a carrier, so I don't think addressing is a problem. Has anyone been able to get this feature to work on 22.04?
Here's my netplan config:
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp26s0f0:
      dhcp4: true
      ignore-carrier: yes
      link-local: [ ipv4 ]

And the resultant logs from networkd:
● 2: enp26s0f0                                                                 >
                     Link File: /usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
                  Network File: /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-enp26s0f0.netwo>
                          Type: ether
                         State: no-carrier (configuring)
                  Online state: offline
             Alternative Names: eno0
                          Path: pci-0000:1a:00.0
                        Driver: i40e
                        Vendor: Intel Corporation
                         Model: Ethernet Connection X722 for 10GBASE-T
                    HW Address: a4:bf:01:6d:8a:e4 (Intel Corporate)
                           MTU: 1500 (min: 68, max: 9702)
                         QDisc: mq
  IPv6 Address Generation Mode: none
          Queue Length (Tx/Rx): 64/64
              Auto negotiation: no
                         Speed: n/a
             Activation Policy: up
           Required For Online: yes

Sep 04 02:55:04 ta systemd-networkd[918]: enp26s0f0: DHCPv6 lease lost
Sep 04 02:57:14 ta systemd-networkd[918]: enp26s0f0: Re-configuring with /run/s>
Sep 04 02:57:14 ta systemd-networkd[918]: enp26s0f0: Re-configuring with /run/s>
Sep 04 02:58:16 ta systemd-networkd[37387]: enp26s0f0: Link UP
Sep 04 02:59:16 ta systemd-networkd[37387]: enp26s0f0: Re-configuring with /run>
Sep 04 02:59:16 ta systemd-networkd[37387]: enp26s0f0: Re-configuring with /run>
Sep 04 03:01:19 ta systemd-networkd[37387]: enp26s0f0: Re-configuring with /run>
Sep 04 03:01:19 ta systemd-networkd[37387]: enp26s0f0: Re-configuring with /run>
Sep 04 03:02:20 ta systemd-networkd[37387]: enp26s0f0: Re-configuring with /run>
Sep 04 03:02:20 ta systemd-networkd[37387]: enp26s0f0: Re-configuring with /run>

These logs and the netplan apply --debug logs don't tell me much, any more info would be much appreciated! My backup plan is to use ifconfig to manually set the static IP for this port. This command works but it's major downside is that the assignment gets randomly lost at times and always lost on reboots.
EDIT:
Using static IP also doesn't work.
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp26s0f0:
      dhcp4: false
      ignore-carrier: yes
      addresses: [ 169.254.20.1/16 ]
      link-local: [ ipv4 ]

Logs:
● 2: enp26s0f0                                                                 >
                     Link File: /usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
                  Network File: /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-enp26s0f0.netwo>
                          Type: ether
                         State: no-carrier (configuring)
                  Online state: offline
             Alternative Names: eno0
                          Path: pci-0000:1a:00.0
                        Driver: i40e
                        Vendor: Intel Corporation
                         Model: Ethernet Connection X722 for 10GBASE-T
                    HW Address: a4:bf:01:6d:8a:e4 (Intel Corporate)
                           MTU: 1500 (min: 68, max: 9702)
                         QDisc: mq
  IPv6 Address Generation Mode: none
          Queue Length (Tx/Rx): 64/64
              Auto negotiation: no
                         Speed: n/a
             Activation Policy: up
           Required For Online: yes


Sep 04 15:27:06 ta systemd-networkd[37387]: enp26s0f0: Re-configuring with /run>
Sep 04 15:27:06 ta systemd-networkd[37387]: enp26s0f0: Re-configuring with /run>

EDIT #2
Trying to configure systemd/network also failed:
[Match]
Name=enp26s0f0

[Network]
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv4
Address=169.254.20.1/16
ConfigureWithoutCarrier=yes

[Link]
ActivationPolicy=always-up

Log:
● 2: enp26s0f0                                                             
                     Link File: /usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
                  Network File: /srv/etc/systemd/network/eno0.network
                          Type: ether
                         State: no-carrier (configuring)
                  Online state: offline
             Alternative Names: eno0
                          Path: pci-0000:1a:00.0
                        Driver: i40e
                        Vendor: Intel Corporation
                         Model: Ethernet Connection X722 for 10GBASE-T
                    HW Address: a4:bf:01:6d:8a:e4 (Intel Corporate)
                           MTU: 1500 (min: 68, max: 9702)
                         QDisc: mq
  IPv6 Address Generation Mode: none
          Queue Length (Tx/Rx): 64/64
              Auto negotiation: no
                         Speed: n/a
             Activation Policy: up
           Required For Online: yes

Sep 05 16:11:11 ta systemd-networkd[2782]: enp26s0f0: Link UP


If this isn't working, please file a bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan.

Also, I would not expect ignore-carrier to allow DHCP to work when there is no actual carrier!

Okay, I'll file a bug report. Thanks for the advice. Good to know about DHCP, I added an edit showing my static IP config, which also fails.

Does this help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/752365/571049

@mpboden sort of, can I piece wise use netplan for some ports and directly use systemd-networkd for other ports?

Netplan is just a backend for stystemd-networkd. Your Netplan config specifies networkd as the renderer. Anyway, I thought that maybe the config for ConfigureWithoutCarrier might be set to false and that you need to change it to true.

Just tried to configure systemd-networkd directly, using ConfigureWithoutCarrier  and ActivationPolicy=always-up, but no luck.

Okay, I figured out the problem. It has to do with how the upstream networking agent systemd-networkd handles link-local addresses. Quoting from the maintainers (src):

DuplicateAddressDetection= is enabled by default for IPv4 link-local addresses (169.254.0.0/16), and IPv4ACD requires the interface has its carrier. Please use something like the following:

[Address]
Address=169.254.1.2/24
DuplicateAddressDetection=none

So my successful networkd configuration looks like this in total:
[Match]
Name=enp26s0f0

[Network]
ConfigureWithoutCarrier=yes
IgnoreCarrierLoss=yes

[Address]
Address=169.254.20.1/16
DuplicateAddressDetection=none

[Link]
ActivationPolicy=always-up

I wasn't able to find a counterpart for this DuplicateAddressDetection option in netplan, maybe that's something that could be added in the future.

Good sleuthing! I saw that as well in my research.
